# Add Material2 attributes to WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm, angular-material2

There are a lot of answers to add Material to AngularJS, but what about Material 2 and Angular 2?

A lot of attributes like `md-raised-button` give a warning because they are not allowed here, even if it's shown in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that webstorm is missing some features,for instance this gives me a duplicate id warning althought that I am loading IDs dynamically and it working perfectly:
[image: Deplicated id Reference]

Nevertheless it is improving  they indicated that the 2017 version will have a better support for angular as it will have an integration with the Angular language service: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/webstorm-2017-1-early-access-preview/

the material2 is a relatively new library compared to material  (its first release was on march 2016) so it is normal  you won't find lot of documentation around it. still the examples in their documentation work fine so  don't worry about the webstorm warnings.

**Update** : I filled an issue on the idea issues track and the material attributes are now supported (starting from Webstorm 2017.2 EAP release ) you might want to try it

Comment: I don't worry about, but it's better to have a project without any warnings. Turning off the errors will produce a lot time in typo searching.

Comment: I posted an issue on the webstorm's issue board and they said it is going to be fixed in the 2017.2 build 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26226#u=1490711615636